# how to setup IPv6 ULA advertisement and -DHCPv6 in home network?

Tags: linux, home-networking, ipv6, dhcp-server

I am on ArchLinux, and I am running IPv6 in my local home network. IPv6-Internet comes with my fritz.box and works well with all clients.

On my home server, I set up `radvd` to advertise my local ULA prefix.

```
  prefix fd04::/64 {  # 
    AdvOnLink on;
    AdvAutonomous on;
    AdvRouterAddr on;
  };
```

This works fine with `::/64` and all clients get some ULA-Adresses like `fd04::aa:bb:cc:dd/64`.

But what I really want is a "human readable" `/112` net, with addresses like `fd04::abcd`.
If I change `radvd.conf` to

```
  prefix fd04::/112 {  
    AdvOnLink on;
    AdvAutonomous on;
    AdvRouterAddr on;
  };
```

...no client would get any ULA address.
logfile states `radvd (909949): eth0 prefix length should be: 64`
Does anyone see whats going wrong with this?

**My second question is**:
I would like to give some static ULA-addresses to some clients. Currently, I hardcoded the clients to give themselves these static addresses.
However, I would like to setup a "small" DHCPv6-server for my home network, that assigns these static ULAs to the clients (e.g. by identifying their MAC addresses).

How would I set this up with linux?

Comment: Basically it is saying that 64 is the maximum length of the prefix, because subnets smaller than /64 are kinda not supported in IPv6.

Answer (score 1):

Researching those topics myself this is what I found for a "small" dhcpv6-server: [dhcpy6d](https://github.com/HenriWahl/dhcpy6d) It does assign addresses to clients based on their MAC. You can config patterns for different classes of addresses in a flexible way and it even does DDNS if the name server is bind9.

Such a pattern might look like
`pattern = fd04::fab:$id$`
and you use it in a class, say alpha_client

and you have a client configured as

```
[beatles]
hostname = beatles
mac = 11:22:33:aa:bb:cc
class = alpha_client
id = 4
```

you can let your RA advertise a /64 and still give short addresses like fd04::fab:4

With DDNS running you can have

```
$ host beatles
beatles.intern has IPv6 address fd04::fab:4
```

Guess that example shows off my age..
That example ignores several relevant RFCs so in case of a merger you may have to renumber.

Another thing might be using IPv6Token with systemd-networkd but that would force you to config it on every single client.